# Notification to Cloud Service Instance when another instance goes down

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service with multiple instances. I'm trying to find a way to notify instance A if instance B goes down. Is there a way to hook into the azure notifications to do this rather than have each instance poll the others?

Answer (score 0):

Polling is simplest approach.  Do be aware that it takes some time for Azure to detect if an instance goes down (depends on how outage occurs and how it is manifested).  In fact, if your app crashes, Azure may not even detect an outage at all.

I'm involved with a product called CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com , it provides sophisticated monitoring/automation for Azure and has a set of features where-by it can call your APIs when it detects issues in an environment.  Perhaps it could be used to detect an issue with your instance and post to an API method that you implement?

HTH